# Why are promises resolved before executing Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, promise

in a node.js program I need to call an API with a POST request after collecting some depending data asynchronously.

The code structure looks basically like this:

```
var promises = [];
for(n records in parentRecord.children) { 
   promises.push( 
     getDetails().then( 
       getDetailsOfDetails().then ( 
          httpRequest("POST", collectedData).then(
            updateRecord(withNewId)
          )
       )
    )
  );
}

result = Promise.all(promises).then( updateParentRecord(withCollectedResults from HTTP responses) );
```

The problem is that everything starting with `getDetails()` is executed twice, so that n*2 http requests are sent.
As you may see from the structure, I am not an expert in promises.
How can the code be restructured so that the promises are resolved only once when Promise.all is resolved?

Comment: This question needs editing. You ask about `getRecord` but there is no `getRecord` in your code. Also, this is not syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: there is no `getRecord` in the code you've shown, also the code is syntactically incorrect in many ways. Please create a [mre].

Comment: You're not using callbacks for `then`. You are just executing the next code right away. It should be`then(() => ...`.

Comment: You could chain promises instead of nesting `.then()` method calls and `then()` expects a callback function and it seems that you are immediately calling the function passed to `.then()` method.

Comment: I edited the question, sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it s close to how it should be in terms of chaining promises.

```
var promises = [];
for (n records in parentRecord.children) {
  promises.push(
    getDetails()
    .then(getDetailsOfDetails)
    .then(_ => httpRequest("POST", collectedData))
    .then(_ => updateRecord(withNewId)))
}


result = Promise.all(promises).then(updateParentRecord(withCollectedResults from HTTP responses));
```

Comment: You probably want to call `updateParentRecord` from the callback function as well.